# ng-repeat not showing any values

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Im working on an application made with AngularJS and Im trying to view data that was collected with http get method from a RESTServer.

I send the GET request from one view and if the request was successful its navigated to another view in angularJS. The views share the same controller and I have an object put in my scope variable that Im trying to repeat through. Here is my controller.

### controller.js

```
function searchCtrl($state, $scope, $http){

$scope.search;
$scope.responses = [];

$scope.submit = function(){

    if($scope.text){
        $http.get("../backend/index.php/user/searchResult?search=" + $scope.text)
                .then(function successCallback (response) {

                $scope.responses = angular.fromJson(response.data.data);
                console.log(typeof($scope.responses));
                $state.go('home.search');
        });


        //$scope.list.push($scope.text);
        //console.log($scope.list);
        //$state.go('home.search');
    }

    };
    console.log($scope.responses);
}
```

And here is the view that Im sending the request from.

### view1.html

```
<div class="row border-bottom">
<nav class="navbar navbar-static-top" role="navigation" style="margin-bottom: 0">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <span minimaliza-sidebar></span>
        <form role="search" class="navbar-form-custom" ng-submit="submit()" ng-controller="searchCtrl">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" placeholder="SÖK" class="form-control" name="top-search" id="top-search" ng-model="text">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-top-links navbar-right">
        <li>
            <a ui-sref="login">
                <i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i> Logga ut
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a ng-click="$root.rightSidebar = !$root.rightSidebar">
                <i class="fa fa-tasks"></i>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>

</nav>
```

Sending the data to view2.html

### view2.html

```
<div class="wrapper wrapper-content animated fadeInRight" ng-controller="searchCtrl">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="ibox float-e-margins">
            <div class="ibox-content">
                <h2>
                    2,160 results found for: <span class="text-navy" ng-model="search">{{search}}</span>
                </h2>
                <small>Request time (0.23 seconds)</small>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="ibox float-e-margins">
            <div class="ibox-title">
                <h3>Media</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="ibox-content">
                <table id="search_result1" class="display table table-striped table-responsive" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                  <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Titel</th>
                            <th>Undertitel</th>
                            <th>ISBN</th>
                            <th>Reg. nr</th>
                            <th>Plats i arkiv</th>
                            <th>Publicister</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr ng-repeat="response in responses">
                            <td>{{response}}</td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Can someone please explain why this is happening? This is not all of my code just the one relevant for my issue.

Comment: Did you verify that `$scope.responses` is not empty?

Comment: what does the `console.log` print?

Comment: when you go to the other view, the controller resets the data

Comment: console.log print [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object] but the ng-repeat is commented out when I view it in my browser.

Comment: Why `$state.go('home.search');` ? You're leaving the current state, that's why it's empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using $stateParams and divide my two views into different controllers. Maybe this would be possible by using the same controllers as well but I think the purpose of $stateParams is to send data between views and I guess Its assumed they also have different controllers.

Here is my **controller.js** now

```
   function MainCtrl($state, $scope) {

  $scope.transportSearch = function(searchString){
        $state.go('home.search', {searchString: searchString });
        console.log(searchString);
    };
}


function SearchCtrl($state, $scope, $http, $stateParams){

    $scope.search;
    $scope.responses = [];
    var searchString = $stateParams.searchString;
    console.log(searchString);  


    $scope.getSearch = function(){

            $http.get("../backend/index.php/user/searchResult?search=" + searchString)
                    .then(function successCallback (response) {

                    $scope.responses = angular.fromJson(response.data.data);

            })

    };
    $scope.getSearch();
}
```

And here is my **config.js** where I send the data via the URL from MainCtrl to SearchCtrl

```
    .state('home.search', {
            url: "/search/:searchString",
            templateUrl: "views/search_results.html",
            data: { pageTitle: 'Search' },
            controller: 'SearchCtrl'
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem i guess is `$state.go('home.search');`, your controller is getting resetted, you can pass your object to `$state.go('home.search', {obj: responses});` and in your new `view` you can access the same as both are of same controller.

```
controller('SameCtrl', function ($state, $scope) {
    $scope.yourFunction = function (obj) {
        $state.go("hom.search", {object: JSON.stringify(obj)});
    }
})
.controller('SameCtrl', function ($state, $scope, $stateParams) {
    if(!$state.params){
        console.log(JSON.parse($state.params.object));
    }
})
```

Comment: Yes It seems like the variables in my controller is getting resetted when I change my view but the {obj: responses} is not making it work either.